# Ionic 2 Contacts Native Plugin not working as expected in real Android device

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I installed the Contacts plugin for Ionic 2 as explained in this documentation:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/contacts/

The reference don't give us any explanation on how to use the plugin and no example of how to find and handle errors.

In an emulator my app works just fine. It lists all the contacts. But in real device it gives me an empty error and no contact is written to the list.

```
Contacts.find(['phoneNumbers']).then((phone_contacts) => {
   self.contacts = {};
  // Some code
}).catch((error) => {
   alert('Contacts error: '+JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

The `error` object is empty and alert prints `{}`.

I installed the app by two different ways:

1- sudo ionic run android
2- copying the android-debug.apk to downloads folder and install it via package manager. I granted the requested permissions.

These two lines are in my Manifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="24" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Anyone got a clue on how I can debug it? Or what could be this error?

**@edit**

It's a Android 4.4.2, KitKat

**@edit 2**

I put the code in my `home.ts`, in constructor, in the `ready` event.

```
platform.ready().then(() => {

});
```

Comment: may be try adding it inside ``platform.ready()``

Comment: see the edit. it is in the ready of home.ts constructor

Comment: from the docs , the type should be of ``ContactFieldType``

Comment: Hey Suraj, im not sure what you meant. I tried my real contacts list in my smartphone, there are around 300 contacts in the list

Comment: Yeah raj, but how do I get this contact field? I saw examples passing strings and it works.in emulator

Comment: According to the [cordova docs](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts#contactfieldtype) of the plugin that ionic-native contacts uses the field type should work..

Comment: havnt worked with contact. But  you can try ``import { ContactField } from 'ionic-native' `` .

Comment: ionic-native is a wrapper for the cordova plugin.. the same repo link is available in the ionic docs page.

Comment: is the plugin added in config.xml?

Answer (score -1):

I have a similar error, in the console.log show this message:

EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: navigator.contacts is undefined
Contacts

This is my code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar, Splashscreen } from 'ionic-native';
import { Contacts } from 'ionic-native';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage = HomePage;

  constructor(platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      Splashscreen.hide();

    Contacts.find(['displayName','name','nickname'], {filter:''})
      .then(
        cont=>{
          console.log(cont[0]);
          alert(JSON.stringify(cont[0]));
        })      
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer. Please see [answer]. This page is not a message board, but a Q&A-site.

Comment: I`m buid proyect for Android. In Genymotion emulator works well.